# Сортировка постов по нескольким условий

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, объекты

У меня есть массив с постами. В обьекте хранится id, text, sub, admin. Нужно сделать так, чтобы обьекты у которых admin = true, были самые первые, а остальные по убыванию sub
То-есть, не смотря что у обьекта(1) мало sub, он должен отображаться первым так как он admin, следующий id3 и так далее, по убыванию sub.

Есть пока сортировка по sub

```
    const posts = [
    {id: 1, text: 'Hi', sub: 4, admin: true},
    {id: 2, text: 'Hello', sub:7,admin: false},
    {id: 3, text: 'By', sub:100,admin: false}
  ]

console.log(posts.sort(function(a,b){

  return  b.sub - a.sub

}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
const posts = [
    {id: 1, text: 'Hi', sub: 4, admin: true},
    {id: 2, text: 'Hello', sub:7,admin: false},
    {id: 3, text: 'By', sub:100,admin: false}
];

console.log(posts.sort((a,b) => b.admin - a.admin || b.sub - a.sub));
```

Тут, в принципе, так и написано: сортируй по админу или (если нет), то по `sub`

`b.admin - a.admin` работает потому, что булева неявно преобразуется в число

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const posts = [{
    id: 1,
    text: 'Hi',
    sub: 4,
    admin: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'Hello',
    sub: 7,
    admin: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'By',
    sub: 100,
    admin: false
  }
]

const sortFunction = (a, b) => {
  if (a.admin == b.admin) {
    return (a.sub > b.sub) ? -1 : (a.sub > b.sub) ? 1 : 0;
  } else {
    return (a.admin > b.admin) ? -1 : 1;
  }
}

console.log(posts.sort(sortFunction))
```